# Firebase adding user node gives Error: PERMISSION_DENIED for new user only

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to firebase so my apology if I'm missing on some obvious things.
I have email/password signup. If successful I want to create a user node in my firebase: user/uid and save some user data:

```
function signUp(){
    console.log('ACTION > SIGNUP AS: ' + $("#loginEmail").val() + '...');
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword($("#loginEmail").val(), $("#loginPsw").val()).then(function(user) {
        // Success 
        console.log('ACTION > SIGNUP SUCCESS');
        console.log('-- SAVING PRIVATE DATA...');
        var userRef = firebase.database().ref("users").child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
        userRef.update({"email": user.email, "displayName": user.displayName, "photoURL": user.photoURL});

    }).catch(function(error){
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        $("#loginErr").text(errorMessage);
    });
}
```

But when signUp is fired I get an error:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/Mcf4MbabvbQB9HzoYEd3Brqthlx2 failed: permission_denied
```

I tried to use "set" instead of "update" and got the same error.

My firebase rule is:

```
    {"rules": {
        "users": {
          "$uid": {
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
          }
        }
    }}
```

Now, if I simply refresh the page, I can run the next code with no errors:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({"test": "1"});
```

I was able to get it working by adding ".write" = true:

```
    {"rules": {
        ".write": true,
        "users": {
          "$uid": {
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
          }
        }
    }}
```

But then users can write anything at the top level.
So why I get PERMISSION_DENIED when after user signs up, but no error if I refresh the page?